# The Manipulate of this plot won't plot regarding projectile motion

Tags: plotting, manipulate

It just plots a blank

```
    y[x_, \[Alpha]_, v_] = x*Tan[\[Alpha]] - 0.5*g*(x/(v*Cos[\[Alpha]]))^2

    Manipulate[ Plot[y[x, \[Alpha], v] , {x , 0 , 10 }], {\[Alpha] , 0 , Pi/2 } , {v , 0 , 10} ] /. g -> 9.8
```

Honestly not sure why...maybe I'm just too tired to see the mistake.

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Plot[y[x, \[Alpha], v] /. g -> 9.8, {x, 0, 10}], {\[Alpha], 0, 
  Pi/2}, {v, 0.0000001, 10}]`

Comment: It still only plots a blank...do you think something is up with the kernel maybe?

Comment: But thank you so much. I see where I made mistakes!

Comment: Yeah, try quitting the kernel and trying again. It works fine for me.

Comment: Cool! will do. So the function it is plotting is fine though?

Comment: I mean, the `Manipulate` isn't really useful here, depending on what you're doing, because the plot is going to automatically scale the axes, so the graph will always just show a parabola of exactly the same shape. But yeah, the function is fine.

Comment: Don't forget to click the green arrow under the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `ReplaceAll` into the 1st argument of `Plot`.

```
y[x_, α_, v_] := x*Tan[α] - 0.5*g*(x/(v*Cos[α]))^2
Manipulate[
  Plot[y[x, α, v] /. g -> 9.8, {x, 0, 10}],
  {α, 0, Pi/2},
  {v, 0.1, 10}]
```

[image: plot]